Stripe 3d-secure authentication flow redirect fails in Iphones
working with Stripe I have implemented their 3d-secure authentication flow -
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/3d-secure/authentication-flow#handle-redirect
The issue I have is specifically with handling the redirect after the 3d secure iframe is done on iPhones, the documentation mentioned using window.top.postMessage from the iframe to alert the parent that the iframe is complete, code example -
Parent -
  window.addEventListener('message', function(ev) {
    if (ev.data === '3DS-authentication-complete') {
      on3DSComplete();
    }
  }, false);


Iframe -
window.top.postMessage('3DS-authentication-complete');

Overall the solution works but it seems like for the past couple of days a lot of our iPhone customers have crashed halfway through, while debugging the issue we found that the message event listener is receiving about 90k events before the one we are manually triggering in the code sample above.
That amount of requests causes the browser to fail and refresh the page some of the times.
In comparison on Android/Desktop, there are only about 2-3 events before ours.
I'm not sure what is it with iPhones for the past few days that causes LOTS of message events to be triggered, we tried refactoring it to use customevents/hashchange but none of these solutions works on cross-origin requests (as the iframe isn't the same origin as the parent).
Did anyone else encounter this issue? any workarounds?
Thanks

Did you receive 90k of the same '3DS-authentication-complete' events? You might want to check your implementation and see if window.top.postMessage('3DS-authentication-complete');  was executed inside a loop.

Nope, just random message events. only a single '3DS-authentication-complete' as per my implementation.
I'm guessing Iphone has some background browser related stuff that triggers thousands of those events? as it happened both on Safari and Chrome on Iphone. while as I said almost none on android/desktop
